# Possible Server Improvements?

Tags: sql-server-2005, odbc, performance

I need an expert insight to my problem. most of my experience is development so i dont have enough grasp regarding server issues or maintenance. Main problem is when traffic is high request to this SQL server times out. there are several applications connecting to this server, some are web some are windows app. i would like to know if i need to do hardware upgrade(more ram, more hdisk space and how much of each is enough) or SQL server maintenance (rebuilding index, SP enhancement, denormalization etc.) or both?

OK first let me give you some specs of the server i'm having trouble with.

- **OS:** MS Windows Server 2003 Standard
- **Version:**     5.2.3790 SP 1 Build 3790
- **System Type:** x64-based PC
- **Processor:** EM64T Family 6 Model 15 Stepping 6 GenuinIntel ~2993 Mhz
- **RAM:** 8gb
- **free C:** space: 400mb
- **SQL Server Soft. Ver.:** Sql Server 2005 Developer Edition

hope info above is enough for a diagnosis. my main concern initially is the available space in c:. also i'm looking at the RAM, i use perfmon and when traffic is high its reaching its max. as for CPU i have no idea but sometimes its running at 100% but its not always like that so i think its normal.

next question i think will be pointless because i cant give you sql db details but i will ask anyway. Will reindexing help or SP optimazation and to what extent? db is at 50+gb now

do we need a new server(hardware)?

Will Updating the sql server software help? from 2005 to 2008? is there an issue when your SQL server prod is only dev edition?

when you have an issue like this what could be the default fix or quick fix if there are any..

I hope an experienced Sys. Ad. or DBA or some programming god have pitty on me and enlighten me regarding this problem

Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe you'll get better results asking this on serverfault

Answer (score 0):

The first step would be to provide more useful information in your question. How does the server behave under pressure.

Use perfmon and or Sql Profiler http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187929.aspx to log a number of data points while it is under load.

Also see [Performance tuning with SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806749/performance-tuning-with-sql-server) and https://serverfault.com/questions/4700/how-to-do-periodic-sql-server-performance-monitoring-and-troubleshooting